# Return view to client from web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to develop a payment gateway web service which can be called from all my other application.I use ASP.net web API for this.

I created an HTTP post service which accepts XML as an input parameter.I will parse this XML.if there is sufficient information it will be redirected to payment page or otherwise it will show a page which collects the sufficient data from user. So it must return a view to user and custom error codes and messages.

These are my needs and I want to know which is the best way to accomplish this.

Can I use web API controller or MVC controller for this?

How will the client show the view returned? Inside iframe is not considered as a good choice for me.Is there any other good ways to show the page?

Comment: Web api controller can`t return a view. If you must return a View you'll need to use a mvc controller.

Comment: How can client render this view @BrunoQuintella

Comment: @vivekv "How can client render this view "...using a browser? What do you mean? What difficulty do you foresee with this? If your controller specifies a redirect, then the browser will redirect.

Comment: I am calling the mvc controller from a seperate angular js application as http service. So how i display the view returned from the web service @BrunoQuintella

Answer (score 0):

You can use RazorEngine to parse view in WebApi.

```
var templatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Views/Payment/Form.cshtml");
var templateContent = File.ReadAllText(templatePath);
var templateString = Razor.Parse(templateContent, new ClassA());
return Ok(new {
        ErrorCode = "000",
        Html = templateString
    });
```

Your can refer this link https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ for quickstart.